AWS Glue job glob exclusion pattern not working
I have a following folder structure in s3.
mybucket:
  - 1-Preparing-<UUID> //UUID is random generated number
    - file1.csv
    - file2.csv
  - 2-Ready-<UUID> //UUID is random generated number
    - file1.csv
    - file2.csv

I want glue job to exclude folder and all the files under "1-Preparing-*".
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    ...
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={
        "paths": ["s3://mybucket/"], 
        "recurse": True, 
        "exclusions": "^1-Preparing-.*"},
    ...
)

I found that regex is not a supported option instead I should be using globbing to exclude the folder according to doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html#crawler-data-stores-exclude
I have also tried excluding it by applying globbing, but still does not work.
...
connection_options={
   "paths": ["s3://mybucket/"], 
   "recurse": True, 
   "exclusions": ["1-Preparing-e8f05ff2-ab20-3a20-1592-4a3c0a9876543/**"]},
...

Can anyone tell why it is not working and suggest simpler solution for it?

Do you see any error in the cloudwatch logs?

For anyone who cares I ended up using python s3 boto client to apply filter and then run the glue job. Glob did not work for me.
